# When using a raw socket for TCP traffic, keep kernel from receiving incoming packets

Tags: security, sockets, testing, iptables

I am running some security tests which require the use of a non-standard TCP socket, to generate a behaviour that a normal TCP stack would not follow. I use a raw socket to generate such traffic.

When the reply from the other end point is received, the TCP connection is unknown to the kernel and issues a RESET. To prevent this from happening, the normal solution is to define an iptables rule that drops all outgoing RESET (e.g. iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -dport 50000 --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP).

However, in my particular case, RESET is also a valid segment to generate during the testing. What I need is a way to filter out all segments from that connection so the kernel TCP stack is not involved and yet have access to all the segments in my raw socket.
Any ideas how can I achieve this? Is this possible with iptables?

Thanks in advance
Luis

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use the host's IP address and fighting Linux's TCP/IP stack is calling for trouble.

Instead, I would use a separate IP address, route that to a tun device and get the raw IP packets from the tun device instead of using a raw socket (some sample code to interface a tun device is available from http://www.secdev.org/projects/tuntap_udp/). That way the Linux TCP/IP stack won't get in your way (except for routing puposes).

Comment: The problem of using a tub device is that the traffic will be internal to the box and I need to test from an external tester box into the system under test. For that reason, I need a way to generate those TCP segments from the tester box, including a RESET.